# Finding A Function For The Harmonic series

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, functions, harmonic-functions

Is it possible to formulate a function that can generate the next number in the harmonic series, for instance:

When $$ y = 4,$$ $$x=1+\frac{1}{2} +\frac{1}{3}+ \frac{1}{4}\ldots$$

Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: There is no function which can sum up an HP finitely.

Comment: Is there an approximation up to say 100?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$ f(n) = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j} $$

---

Okay, that's a little facetious. There are other representations and approximations of the harmonic numbers -- you can look through the answers to the question Martin R posted above, and there's a [summary on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation).

But, suppose I rephrase your question like this:

> Is there a function which exactly computes the $n^{th}$ harmonic number faster than simply computing the partial sum?

To my knowledge, there is not.

Comment: This doesn't seem to do it.

Comment: @JinnyEcckle I edited my answer

Comment: Is there a function that generates the numbers up reasonably high y values? Say 100, or 1000? Thanks for your time!!

Comment: There are lots of functions that generate them up to 100 or 1000. For instance you could find the Lagrange polynomial interpolating $\{ (n, H_n)\ |\ n=1,\ldots,1000\}$ and use that to compute $H_n$. However it will have degree $1000$ so evaluating will use about as many computations as simply adding $1+\frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \cdots$.

Comment: Thank you! I'm using it for to make an expression for graphing; so, I need an actual function. Is there a more compacted way to do it?

Comment: $H_n = \sum_{j=1}^n \frac{1}{j}$ is an actual function.